# How reproduce sha256 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, bash

I actually use an implementation like the dice contract : https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/v1.2.0/contracts/dice

You create a key and his hash with sha256, you first send the hash and then the key to the smart-contract. The contract use the function assert_sha256. I have difficulty for creating the hash with sha256 in Javascript. The encryption has to be the same than the EOS contract else assert_sha256 fail.

I try with the function sha256 of eosjs-ecc and other library without success.

In the dice contract example, they do it in shell like this

```
echo -n 'abc' | xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b | awk '{print $1}'
```

I don't understand all the parameters particularly xxd. It translates in binary ?

Thanks

EDIT :

Thanks Don, I spend a lot of time to understand how pass hex to binary, how xxd work, etc... but the answer was just in front of my eyes.

In the documentation of ecc : https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc
You just have to pass your hex key inside of this code

```
ecc.sha256(Buffer.from('02208b', 'hex'))
```

The first time, I probably didn't pass hex data so it's failed.

Comment: /akexabdre ah, gotcha. glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xxd`    make a hexdump or do the reverse

`-r`     revert, convert hexdump into binary

`-p` output 'plain hexdump style'

`sha256sum`  compute and check SHA256 message digest

`-b`  read in binary mode

Here the combination of `-r -p` options for the `xxd` command will read plain hexadecimal dumps without line number information and without a particular column layout allowing whitespace and linebreaks.

from the [eosjs-ecc documentation](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc#sha256):

> ## **sha256**
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `data` (string | Buffer) always binary, you may need
>     Buffer.from(data, 'hex')
> - `resultEncoding` (optional, default 'hex')
> - `encoding` string result encoding 'hex', 'binary' or 'base64' (optional,
>     default 'hex')
>
> **Examples**
>
> `ecc.sha256('hashme') === '02208b..'`,
>    `ecc.sha256(Buffer.from('02208b', 'hex')) === '29a23..'`
>
> Returns (string
>   | Buffer) Buffer when encoding is null, or string

There are also scripts & packages available for implementing sha256 algo. [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256)

Depending on where/when you are trying to implement using javascript, there are [some issues/concerns to consider.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338890/are-there-any-sha-256-javascript-implementations-that-are-generally-considered-t)